# Getting an Error `custom program error: 0x26` on Minting an NFT?

Tags: solana, metaplex

This is the Program Logs that I am getting when i try to create an NFT

[image: This is the Program Logs that I am getting when i try to create an NFT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error describes itself that the person who is minting the NFT address should also be part of the creator's array to solve this error you have to add the address of the account who is signing the transaction as a Creator in the Data Struct.

If you don't wish to add the person signing's address into the creator struct you can either set the share for that address as 0 or update the NFTs metadata after minting the NFT.